# How to call a vanilla JavaScript function from a node js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mocha.js

I'm working on writing some mocha unit tests for a vanilla JavaScript file, mainWindow.js. This JS file creates UI components and carries out client calls to the backend node.js server for data. The first test in mainWindow.spec.js I'm trying to write is to test the GET function in mainWindow.js. How do I do a direct call of this function? See snippets below.

#### mainWindow.js

```
var mainWindow = {
    downloadRoles: function (voiceInput) {
        var word = voiceInput.procedureNumber;
        var number = mainWindow.wordToNumber(word);
        mainWindow.currentProcedure = mainWindow.mission[number - 1];

        $.get({
                url: mainWindow.urlprefix + "/hud/api/roles/" + mainWindow.currentProcedure,
                dataType: "JSON"
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Failed to download mission data");
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                mainWindow.roles = data;
                mainWindow.selectRole();
            });
    },

module.exports = downloadRoles();
```

#### mainWindow.spec.js

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var $ = require('jquery')(new jsdom.JSDOM().window);
var app = require('../js/mainWindow');
var mock = require('mock-require');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var passThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
var http = require('http');

mock('jquery', $);
mock.reRequire('jquery');


describe('frontend client testing', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.request = sinon.stub(http, 'request');
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        http.request.restore();
    })
    it('should initialize a window object', function() {
        assert.typeOf(app, 'object');
    })
    it('should GET a JSON response', function(done) {
        var expected = {};
        var response = new PassThrough();
        response.write(JSON.stringify(expected));
        response.end();

        var request = new PassThrough();

        this.request.calls().returns(request);

        app.downloadRoles();
    })
})
```

### Update 1

I'm exporting downloadRoles(), however, when calling it in mainWindow.spec.js, I'm getting the error ReferenceError: downloadRoles is not defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what mainWindow.js exports, and that part is missing above.

Comment: @terrymorse I can't seem to export anything. Linter shows an error.

Comment: @terrymorse Updated to show export statement. Error thrown is ReferenceError: downloadRoles is not defined

Comment: That export statement looks wrong. It’s exporting the return value from downloadRoles, which runs immediately with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
module.exports = downloadRoles();
```

That is exporting the results of running `downloadRoles()', clearly not what you want.

Export this:

```
module.exports.downloadRoles = mainWindow.downloadRoles; // no '()'
```

Then in your test page:

```
const { downloadRoles } = require('../js/mainWindow');
...
downloadRoles();
```